# List of all subscription

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

How to check all report's subscriptions on Sharepoint 2010?

I know only how to check subsciption on specific report:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way way for you to do this from the GUI.  You are going to have to break out PowerShell to get this information.

NOTE: I haven't tested this code, kinda writing it from the hip, but the gist should be able to help you out.:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb <Site reports are contained in>
$spRepList = $spWeb.Lists["<List containing reports Name>"];
#Get all files
$spFileList = $spRepList.Files;

foreach($spFile in $spFileList)
{
   #determine if the file is a report or a regular document
   if($spFile.URL -like "*.rdl")
   {
      $reportServiceProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -URI <url to the reporting web service> -Namespace <Namespace of the service> -UseDefaultCredentials
      $subscriptionList += $reportServiceProxy.ListSubscriptions($site);

      #From here you can write to a file or write to the screen.  I will let you decide
      $subscriptionList | select Path, report, Description, Owner, SubscriptionID, lastexecuted,Status | where {$_.path -eq $spFile.URL}
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Dave

Comment: Could you give me more details, what I have to put in <> ?

Comment: I am not too sure what else I can give you as it is your environment.  However, for Get-SPWeb you will need the URL of your site, the list is where the reports are stored (ex. Shared Documents).  I couldn't begin to know what your web service address would be, you will need to get that from your admins.  
I am not sure if this will help any further, but you could use this site for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/dn747196.aspx#bkmk_list_for_1_report
The information there might help.  My script builds on it though.